# WGS84 to local coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, c#, proj, revit

I have a point cloud and would like to move this to the local coordinate system for example from Revit facing toward the first quadrant. We have a file with 3 ground reference points and on-site marked with blocks. So it is possible for us to get the coordinates from the point cloud so, we have:

- 3 ground reference points in RDNew
- 3 reference points in the point cloud from the 3 blocks
- an Origin point for the absolute 0,0,0 coordinates

We want to move the point cloud to the local coordinate system and rotate towards the first quadrant.

How can I perform this transformation with for example a proj4 string?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Your title says WGS84 (latitude,longitude) but the body of the question implies that the point cloud coordinates are in a local xyz system. Which one is correct?